# Dereferencing COM object in C# application

Tags: c#, com

C# based application is invoking the object by following code

```
var COMType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(progID, server);

if (COMType == null)
{
    return false;
}

_messageRouter = Activator.CreateInstance(COMType);
```

After this line number of object incremented in Component server
[enter image description here][1]

so when the job is done I need to clear the object and decrement the count of the Object.

Here is the below code I am using to clear it out and decrementing, the object is successfully set to null but not decrementing the object count.

Below is the cleaning code.

```
if (_messageRouter != null)
{
   Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_messageRouter);
}
            
_messageRouter = null;
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CTCV.png Component Server

Comment: ReleaseComObject https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject just decrements the reference count of the Runtime Callable Wrapper (RCW) associated with the COM object. _messageRouter  seems to indicate you keep that as a member variable, so it's probably still used.

Comment: _messageRouter is a class member when I used ReleaseComObject it did`nt help to decrement the number. I also tried to use Release() and the result is same